# Visual Studio 2015 and MongoDB package installation failed

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, package

I am trying to learn `MongoDB` via `Visual Studio`. I watched some tutorials. It wants me to add a `MongoDB c# driver` reference and some other references to use it with `c#` in the visual studio.

However, when I try to install packages, it gives me an error like this. Here is the error. Do you have any idea, what can I do?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Could not install package 'MongoDB.Bson 2.2.4'. You are trying
>   to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Find the compatible .Net version for the required library and update your project's target version accordingly.

Comment: I randomly found that but it took me 5 hours to do that. Is there any easy way to find the compatible version? Mine was netframe work version=4.5.2